# Run custom script after iOS app is signed in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

As stated in the title, I'm trying to configure the XCode to run a custom script after the iOS app is built and signed.

I added a new build phase in the **Build Phase** section of the iOS target as shown below.

[image]

To my surprise, the script is run before the app is signed. Is there anyway to configure the script to run after the app is signed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We probably need to run the script as part of a separate target. We can just pair them together in an **aggregate target**, and use that wherever we want to use the original target.